# Shiny deployment error (exited with code 1). How would I fix this?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to publish an app to shinyapps.io

It works locally, but not when I try to publish it.

> An error has occurred The application failed to start (exited with
>   code 1).

Then:

> Warning in utils::install.packages(package, ...) :   'lib =
>   "/opt/R/3.6.1/lib/R/library"' is not writable Error in
>   value[3L] : unable to install packages Calls: local ...
>   tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->  Execution
>   halted

Any ideas?

Comment: I have had a bit more of a look. I might be related to using `pacman`. Still testing. https://github.com/trinker/pacman/issues/82

Comment: That was the issue.